# Change/Edit non-expanded gnome-panel handles

Tags: gnome-panel, themes

I set my gnome-panel to behave like a wingpanel (floating panel at the right top corner of the screen):
[image: Unmaximized]
[image: Maximized]

I edited the background to match the window titlebar background, but those handles (the two black points on the edges of the panel) are annoying me, I know it's impossible to remove them, but I want to know where is their image (png, jpg, whatever), because I know it can be changed/edited as each theme has it's own handle. I already looked for it over all the /usr/share/theme folder, only one theme had the handles image in it's folder, others don't, I made several searches for anything related, but I got anything.

Please, mainly those who creates themes, help me. It's not in the /usr/share/theme or icon directories neither in the ~./.theme/ directory.

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 9.10, but any information of users of 10.04 and 10.10 are useful.

Comment: Localised issue